# How to read form data from the child into the parent?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-final-form

I'm using a manually crafted form generator and using [React Final Form](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/) to manage the state and data. The problem now is, I need from a component outside the form to read the data before is even submitted to show the user the actual status of how the input is looking.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { I18n } from 'react-i18nify';
import * as INPUTTYPES from '../../constants/inputTypes';
import { CONCAT_ID_BASES } from '../../constants/config';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import { Form, Field } from 'react-final-form'
const weblog = require('webpack-log');
const log = weblog({ name: 'wds' }) // webpack-dev-server

class FormGenerator extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        fields: PropTypes.any,
        prefix: PropTypes.any,
        children: PropTypes.any
    }

    state = {
        data: {}
    }

    sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

    onSubmit = async values => {
        await this.sleep(300)
        window.alert(JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2))
    }

    static simpleMemoize = fn => {
        let lastArg
        let lastResult
        return arg => {
            if (arg !== lastArg) {
                lastArg = arg
                lastResult = fn(arg)
            }
            return lastResult
        }
    }

    static textValidate = FormGenerator.simpleMemoize(async value => {
        if (!value) {
            return I18n.t('error-no-text-written');
        }
        //await sleep(400)
        if (value.trim().length() > 0) {
            return I18n.t('error-no-text-found');
        }
    })

    static createInput = (newKey, value, validate) => {
        let data = {
            type: value.type,
            //disabled: typeof value.editable !== "undefined" ? !value.editable : false,
            className: "form-control",
            id: `${newKey}`,
            value: value.value
        }
        return <Field key={newKey} name={data.id} validate={validate}>
            {({ input, meta }) => (
                <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label htmlFor={`${newKey}`}>{I18n.t(`${newKey}`)}</label>
                    <input {...data} {...input} />
                    {meta.error && meta.touched && <span>{meta.error}</span>}
                </div>
            )}
        </Field>
    }

    static createSelectInput = (newKey, value) => {
        let data = {
            type: value.type,
            disabled: typeof value.editable !== "undefined" ? !value.editable : false,
            className: "form-control",
            id: `${newKey}`,
            value: value.value
        }
        return <React.Fragment key={newKey}>
            <div className="form-group col-md-6">
                <label htmlFor={`${newKey}`}>{I18n.t(`${newKey}`)}</label>
                <input {...data} />
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    }

    initialValues = function () {
        let { prefix, fields } = this.props;
        prefix = prefix ? prefix + CONCAT_ID_BASES : '';
        fields ? fields.map((field) => {
            const newKey = `${prefix}${field.key}`
            this.setState((prevState) => {
                let newData = { ...prevState.data };
                newData[newKey] = field.value.value;
                return { data: newData };
            })
        }) : null;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.initialValues();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        //console.log(this.state)
        //this.props.suscribeCallback(values)
    }

    inputGenerator(field, prefix) {
        const { key, value } = field;
        const { type } = value;
        const textValidate = FormGenerator.textValidate;
        const newKey = `${prefix}${key}`
        let element = null;
        const createInput = FormGenerator.createInput;

        switch (true) {
            case new RegExp(INPUTTYPES.TEXT.join("|"), "i").test(type):
                value.type = "text";
                element = createInput(newKey, value, textValidate)
                break;
            case new RegExp(INPUTTYPES.NUMBER.join("|"), "i").test(type):
                value.type = "number";
                element = createInput(newKey, value, textValidate)
                break;
            case new RegExp(INPUTTYPES.SELECT.join("|"), "i").test(type):
                break;
            default:
                log.error("DATA NOT ITENDIFIED TYPE:" + type, key, value);
                break;
        }
        return element;
    }

    render() {
        let fields = this.props.fields;
        let { prefix } = this.props;
        prefix = prefix ? prefix + CONCAT_ID_BASES : ''
        const { inputGenerator, onSubmit } = this;

        return (
            <Form
                onSubmit={onSubmit}
                initialValues={this.state.data}
                render={({ values }) => {
                    return <div className="form-row">
                        {fields.map((field) => {
                            return inputGenerator(field, prefix);
                        })}
                        <pre>{JSON.stringify(values, 0, 2)}</pre>
                    </div>
                }} />
        )
    }
}

export default FormGenerator;
```

And calling it like this:

```
{
                detalles ? (() => {
                  return <FormGenerator
                    suscribeCallback={this.formDataChange}
                    prefix={this.props.prefix}
                    fields={detalles} />
                })() : null
              }
```

But now the issue is, I need to read `values` outside the `<Form/>` so I can read it in it's parent.

If I include a call back and toss it into the render method `this.props.suscribeCallback(values)` it will try to call it so much it will crash the site. Of course this is not a valid solution but I don't know how to solve it.

I'm kind of new to Reactjs so appologize if this is a beginner's mistake

Comment: Can you show the code for the whole component?

Comment: Yes! I totally can. I just updated the question

Comment: You could use the validate method of the Form to do this.
It's likely fired every time something changes. (validate is supposed to return an error though so be mindful of that part)

Answer (score 0):

If you need form data outside of the form, I'd suggest using something like the patterns explored in the [Redux Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/4xq2qpzw79), where a `FormStateToRedux` component is listening to changes in form state and sending it...somewhere. It needn't be to Redux.